# iPad equivalent of onmousemove?

Tags: javascript, events, mobile-safari, compatibility

I'm trying to get a website to work on my iPad but the only thing that isn't working is the onmousemove method. I would like onmousemove to be triggered when the user pans their finger across the screen.

Comment: Maybe try `ontouchmove` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events

Comment: @Ian That sounds like it fits [based on the first line of this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events#Drawing_as_the_touches_move). Would you like to post that as an answer, so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of a `mousemove` event in a touch-enabled device is the `touchmove` event.

So you might bind the event like this:

```
var addEvent = (function () {
    var tester, allHandlers, attachGenerator, addFunc, removeFunc;

    tester = document.createElement("div");
    allHandlers = [];

    attachGenerator = function (el, cb) {
        var ret;
        ret = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            cb.call(el, e);
        };
        return ret;
    };

    if (tester.addEventListener) {
        addFunc = function (element, eventName, callback) {
            allHandlers.push({
                element: element,
                eventName: eventName,
                callback: callback
            });
            element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
        };
        removeFunc = function (element, eventName, callback) {
            element.removeEventListener(eventName, callback);
        };
    } else if (tester.attachEvent) {
        addFunc = function (element, eventName, callback) {
            var finalCallback;
            finalCallback = attachGenerator(element, callback);
            allHandlers.push({
                element: element,
                eventName: eventName,
                callback: finalCallback
            });
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, finalCallback);
        };
        removeFunc = function (element, eventName, callback) {
            element.detachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
        };
    }

    addFunc(window, "unload", function () {
        var i, j, cur;
        // Don't remove this unload handler
        for (i = 1, j = allHandlers.length; i < j; i++) {
            cur = allHandlers[i];
            removeFunc(cur.element, cur.eventName, cur.callback);
        }
    });

    return addFunc;
}());

function loadHandler() {
    addEvent(document, "touchmove", touchmoveHandler);
}

function touchmoveHandler() {
    // this callback should fire for every pixel (or whatever unit they may use) the touch moves
}

addEvent(window, "load", loadHandler);
```

(the `addEvent` function is just a general event binding function to help work in old IE...probably unnecessary if you're binding to `touch` events)

Note that my original generic `addEvent` function isn't perfect: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/08/addevent_consid.html , but I modified what I used to use better support the availability of `this` inside the handler when `attachEvent` has to be used, and also to remove all handlers when the window's `unload` event occurs.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/touchmove
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events

Comment: I'm under the impression that [addEvent() is not a good piece of code to use](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/08/addevent_consid.html) - or to use blindly, at least, without being aware of the dangers. +1 otherwise!